# tabulator possible bug - error adding column calcs when there is a nested table

Tags: tabulator

I handled a problem, but it feels like a bug with a work-around rather than how it should function under ideal conditions.  If I try to add bottomCalc to a table with a nested sub-table I get errors.  either the bottomCalc or the nested data table work by themselves, the problem comes from combining the two.

the issue is with the rowFormatter that adds the nested table. the "bottomCalc" row is added to the table and the rowFormatter function is called, but the bottomCalc row obviously doesn't have any nested data, hence the error "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" from tabulator.min.js

notice the if statement in my code (adapted from Tabulator examples) right at the beginning of the rowFormatter checking if the row has serviceHistory data. it feels like a work-around to me, but that is what I needed to get past the error.

```
function toggleNestedTable(){   
    var fordHistory = [
        {date:"01/02/2016", engineer:"Steve Boberson", actions:"Changed oli filter", cost:75.99},
        {date:"07/02/2017", engineer:"Martin Stevenson", actions:"Break light broken", cost:28.99}];

    var detailTables = document.getElementsByClassName("detailTable")
    for (var x = 0; x< detailTables.length; x++){
        detailTables[x].parentNode.removeChild(detailTables[x]);
    }

    var emptyArray = [];

    if(table.getRow(1).getData().serviceHistory.length == 0){
        table.getRow(1).update({"serviceHistory":fordHistory});
    } else {
       table.getRow(1).update({"serviceHistory":emptyArray});
    }
}

var table;

function loadTabulator(){
    var tableData = [
        {id:1, make:"Ford", model:"focus", reg:"P232 NJP", color:"white", serviceHistory:[], cost:3102.55},
        {id:2, make:"BMW", model:"m3", reg:"W342 SEF", color:"red", serviceHistory:[], cost:123 },
        {id:3, make:"Smurf", model:"28", reg:"WLHUNG", color:"porple", serviceHistory:[], cost:7654.00},]

    table = new Tabulator("#test2", {
        layout:"fitData",
        resizableColumns:false,
        data:tableData,
        columns:[
            {title:"Make", field:"make"},
            {title:"Model", field:"model"},
            {title:"Registration", field:"reg"},
            {title:"Color", field:"color"},
            {title:"Cost", field:"cost", formatter:"money", align:"right", bottomCalc:"sum", bottomCalcFormatter:"money", bottomCalcFormatterParams:{decimal: ".", thousand: ","}},
        ],
        rowFormatter:function(row){
            if (row.getData().serviceHistory){
                //create and style holder elements
                var holderEl = document.createElement("div");
                var tableEl = document.createElement("div");

                holderEl.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
                holderEl.style.padding = "10px 30px 10px 10px";
                holderEl.style.borderTop = "1px solid #333";
                holderEl.style.borderBotom = "1px solid #333";
                holderEl.style.background = "#ddd";
                holderEl.classList.add("detailTable");

                tableEl.style.border = "1px solid #333";

                if (row.getData().serviceHistory.length > 0){
                    holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);

                    row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);
                    //holderE1.classList.add("detailTable");

                    var subTable = new Tabulator(tableEl, {
                        layout:"fitData",
                        data:row.getData().serviceHistory,
                        columns:[
                            {title:"Date", field:"date", sorter:"date"},
                            {title:"Engineer", field:"engineer"},
                            {title:"Action", field:"actions"},
                            {title:"Cost", field:"cost", formatter:"money", align:"right", bottomCalc:"sum", bottomCalcFormatter:"money", bottomCalcFormatterParams:{decimal: ".", thousand: ","}},
                        ]
                    })
                }
            }
        },
    });
}
```

is this the best way to handle this?

Comment: As per my knowledge nested rows should have same columns, in your example you are trying to create a 'table' inside another table

Comment: "nested table" is different from "nested row".  see example http://tabulator.info/examples/4.2#nested-tables

Answer (score 0):

I don't properly understand the requirement here, but you are getting the error because you are initializing the table with serviceHistory Data, instead you should set the Data as in this fiddle  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/unLc07om/28/). Hope this helps

```
subTable.setData(row.getData().serviceHistory);
```

Comment: ok, just clarifying to make sure I understand. if I initialize the detail table without data then assign the data with subTable.setData() I should avoid this error. right?